# multiple actions in list comprehension python

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I would like to know how to perform multiple commands in a list comprehension.

Can you give me an example for something simple like:

```
[print ("bla1") and print ("bla2") for i in list]
```

so for a list of 4 length 4 I would have:

```
bla1
bla2
bla1
bla2
bla1
bla2
bla1
bla2
```

Dtrangely enough I didn't easily find it in the documentation. (If you can see an obvious reason why I didn't and can let me know how should I search for such stuff that would be even better).

EDIT: OK, that was a very bad example according to comments.
I *am* interested in creating a new from an old one but I feel that I need two commands to do that. (not a simple print, of course).
For example. I have a list of lists, and I want to create a list that is a result of manipulation of the sublists.

Comment: If you make your list comprehensions too complicated they are likely to become... incomprehensible!

Comment: In Python 3, where `print` is a function, a simple variant of that code will work. It's still a bad way to do it, though.

Comment: "two commands"?  Can you provide examples of what you think you mean by this?  It's not clear.  A "command" doesn't have any formal Python meaning.  Do you mean "statement"?  If so, a list comprehension can't work.  Do you mean "function" or "expression"?  If so, an example would help clarify why it's two expressions.

Comment: You can't have assignments in a list comprehension -- they're statements, and you can only have expressions. You _can_ fake it for functions -- to call a function, ignore its return value, then do something else, use `[(func_call(whatever) or True) and something_else for whatever in your_list]`. Since functions that modify an object in-place return `None`, this allows you to do something like `[lst.extend([1, 2]) or lst for lst in [[1], [2], [3], [4]]]` to get `[[1, 1, 2], [2, 1, 2], ...]`. __Disclaimer:__ Don't do this, a regular loop would be much clearer. (Swoops away for several days)

Comment: I find a solution for your question, please go ahead and select the right answer.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Don't use list comprehension for commands. List comprehensions are for *creating lists*, not for commands. Use a plain old loop:

```
for i in list:
    print('bla1')
    print('bla2')
```

List comprehensions are wonderful amazing things full of unicorns and chocolate, but they're not a solution for everything.

Comment: You're right. I clarified what I meant, hopefully without the negative connotations now.

Comment: Is there anything in PEP that specifies this or is it just a convention that people tend to follow? I see plenty of people using list-comps for commands.

Comment: Just a convention, and best practice.

Comment: Upvoting you for unicorns and chocolate.  Also because this was my same question.

Comment: but the unicorns dancing in the list look so pretty.. can anyone direct me to something to suggest why it's best practice?

Answer (score 48):

You can use tuple for doing that job like this:

```
[(print("bla1"), print("bla2")) for i in list]
```

it's work correctly.

Comment: this helped me... just wondering why writing it within `tuple` worked?

Comment: @joel.wilson That's because for creating the `tuple`, python processes both elements. The `and` operation processes the second operand only if the first operation returns `True`. (Note that `print` always returns `None`, which has a truth value of `False`.

Answer (score 11):

In some cases, it may be acceptable to call a function with the two statements in it.

```
def f():
   print("bla1")
   print("bla2")

[f() for i in l]
```

Can also send an argument to the function.

```
def f(i):
   print("bla1 %d" % i)
   print("bla2")

l = [5,6,7]

[f(i) for i in l]
```

Output:

```
bla1 5
bla2
bla1 6
bla2
bla1 7
bla2
```

Answer (score 4):

If "I need two commands" means that there are two functions, they must be related in some way.

```
def f( element ):
    return intermediate

def g( intermediate ):
    return final

new_list = [ g(f(x)) for  x in old_list ]
```

If that's not appropriate, you'll have to provide definitions of functions which (a) cannot be composed and yet also (b) create a single result for the new sequence.

Answer (score 2):

1. List comprehensions are only for generating data in list form, not for executing statements (or any other side effect, like writing to a file) multiple times. Use a `for` look for that.
2. Assuming you want to generate a list `['bla1', 'bla2', 'bla1', ...]`: You can't do it in general, each iteration puts a single result value into the list. That value may be a list itself, but then you have a list of lists.
3. In specific cases like your example, it's possible though: Use `['bla' + str(i + 1) for x in list for i in range(2)]`, which iterates over `range(2)` for every `x in list`, and thus generates two values per item in `list`. (`list` is a bad name for a variable though, as it's already taken by the builtin.)

Answer (score 0):

Use list comprehension only for creating lists. Your example doesn't use the values of your list at all.

According to the docs: 
"List comprehensions provide a concise way to create lists from sequences."

```
for i in range(len(your_list)):
  print "blah1"
  print "blah2"
```

In the above program, we didn't even care about the values in the list. If you were looking for a different application of list comprehension than what you stated in your problem, then do post.

Answer (score 0):

For what it worth it is possible to use list.append in the list comprehension to produce a new list while ignoring the primary output of the list comprehension. The OP mentions a list of lists. Take for example:

```
>>> master = [range(x,x+2) for x in range(10)]
>>> master
[[0, 1], [1, 2], [2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5], [5, 6], [6, 7], [7, 8], [8, 9], [9, 10]]
```

Then create a new list by manipulating each sublist (as the OP described in the edit)

```
>>> new_list = []
>>> [[new_list.append(l[0]*l[1]),new_list.append(l[0]+l[1])] for l in master]

[[None, None], [None, None], [None, None], [None, None], [None, None], [None, None], [None, None], [None, None], [None, None], [None, None]]

>>> new_list

[0, 1, 2, 3, 6, 5, 12, 7, 20, 9, 30, 11, 42, 13, 56, 15, 72, 17, 90, 19]
```

This does spit out a redundant list of lists with Nones, but also fills the variable new_list with the product and sum of the sublists.

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension, and relations ( set comprehenson, dictionary comprehension, generator expression ) are all syntax that enables expression of a loop within a single command. Pedantics who fail to recognise that fact are limiting Python needlessly, and those who preach the gospel of 'best practice' hobble their followers with pointless dogma. It isn't just for sequences anymore! Execute commands all you want, if that is the cleanest solution. Not using the output of the expression ( often a list like [None, None] ) isn't any worse than a temporary 'variable' going out of scope after a method / function is completed.